# Como passar mais de um middleware Can no laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

Olá, preciso passar várias defines para uma rota, por exemplo admin, plano anual, e new-user, quando coloco o can no middleware ele só identifica o primeiro parâmetro.

AuthServiceProvider.php

```
Gate::define("new-user","App\Policies\ACLChecker@checkerNewUser");
        Gate::define("plano-anual","App\Policies\ACLChecker@checkerPlanoAnual");
Gate::define("admin","App\Policies\ACLChecker@checkerAdmin");
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->middleware("can:plano-anual,new-user,admin");
```

Debug:

```
Gate::after(function ($user, $ability, $result, $arguments) {
            //
            dd($user->plano, $ability, $result, $arguments);

        });
```

Comment: Mano o can na rota funciona assim,o primeiro é o nome da ação que queremos autorizar e o segundo é o parâmetro de rota que desejamos passar para o método de política.

Comment: eu preciso ter controle dessas categorias no layout, tem outra forma de faze-los? @JoanMarcos

Comment: Mais para travar o usuário que não fizer o pagamento.